# Is it possible to debug python script called by JAVA Process Builder

Tags: java, python, debugging

I'm executing python scripts from Java Process Runner, is there any way I could debug python scripts?

Though we could add some print statements and see the log messages, but looking for real debugging, the way we do it for Java in Eclipse.

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("idf.py")

Comment: Yes you can debug your python programs in Eclipse much like you can with Java programs. http://charmyin.github.io/python/2014/11/09/debugger-python-remotely/ https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Python/article.html#debugging

Comment: Thanks Erwin, let me check this.